# PhpStorm doesn't find Linux Mint system variables

Tags: docker, terminal, phpstorm, linux-mint

I've installed Docker on Mint and then PhpStorm. When I try to use docker command in PhpStorm terminal I have this error message

> docker: command not found

At the same time it works well in Mint terminal. `Path` variable value and `whoami` have same value in both terminals; also PhpStorm doesn't find other modules, code sniffer for example.

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Maybe it does not read `.bashrc` or alike file... What about other commands -- do they show the same behaviour? Will it work if you start PhpStorm not via GUI (clicking on icon on app launcher/desktop) but from terminal? Try that.

Comment: Storm was installed via App Manager, in flatpack folder and doesn't has terminal command for launch

Comment: I'm not a Linux person so do not know how that works/the difference, but I think it still worth mentioning that moment in the actual question body. No other ideas then from me (on actual resolving the issue). But just in case: if you install PhpStorm via [JetBrains Toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) -- will it work better this way?

Comment: Stupid question but anyway: did you restart PhpStorm after installing Docker? Did you try to re-login in Mint?

Answer (score 0):

Flatpak installs apps in isolated sandboxes. It's not a recommended way of installation for IntelliJ apps. Download the tar.gz file from the website, use a shell startup script and it will work correctly.